# Iterator inside iterator

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build an iterator over the rows of a table and i'm using a lib that read this. That lib had a proper iterator. I want to know how to chain these two iterator, i mean, when i call next on my iterator the next of the lib calls too.

```
impl Iterator for MyStruct {
  type Item = item;

  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    records().next()
  }
}
```

I did that, but this calls only the first next every time, i want all the rows of the lib iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `records()` inside of the `next()` function, you are creating a new iterator every time, so you start from the beginning at every `next()` call.

You need to store the `records` iterator in the struct and then re-use it instead of re-creating it every time. That way it keeps its state between calls.

Look at this example:

```
fn records() -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
    (1..5).into_iter()
}

struct MyStruct {
    records_iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            records_iter: Box::new(records()),
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for MyStruct {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.records_iter.next()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_obj = MyStruct::new();

    for element in my_obj {
        println!("{}", element);
    }
}
```

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: @CyroAlves you can vote on answers to your own questions without needing rep. If you accept a helpful answer with the check button, you even earn a couple points. see the [create a post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) privileges to know what you can do!

Comment: @JeremyMeadows I'm not sure? I think even on your posts you cannot upvote until 15 rep. But I long forgot that :)

Comment: if that's the case, they should change that page I linked to not suggest "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." I also forget though xD